# react-native android application to fetch and display data from google-spreadsheet

Tags: android, react-native, google-sheets

Am storing some data(eg:temperature) in the google spread sheet. So now i want to fetch the data from my google spread sheet and display it in my react native android application. Can some one give me some ideas or example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is public:

**1 - Publish the file** (File menu, publish)

More details here:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en

**2 - Make a GET request** to

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/<SPREAD_SHEET_ID>/od6/public/values?alt=json
```

or to

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/<SPREAD_SHEET_ID>/<SHEET_NUMBER>/public/basic?hl=en_US&alt=json
```

Source: 
https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample

Notes:

- I tested both urls from above and they work OK but it would be good to make sure you are accessing the latest Google API. The endpoints I provided are for API_V3 but a V4 has been released recently.

  To migrate and use V4 endpoints check these links:
  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration
  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading

  To use the V4 you'll need to set and use use an API_KEY
- If you make too many requests to google for the data you might have to consider some caching.

**3. Extract the data you need from the response** and format it according to your needs.

If your data is not public you have to authorize the request:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing.

I would probably consider using a node package to handle the private data case
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42765674/1979861

Comment: what should i do if my data is not a published one? how can i call the get request for my spreadsheet which is authenticated and not published?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v0uLMSQjUR_pr1KapXceLWnxFsTF5iNFvNX7NLOnRAE/pubhtml this is my doc this is published so what is the url i should call a get request?

Comment: so i now able to get the data from google spreadsheet and thanks alot for the help mate!!!! now how can i add the data to the google spreadsheet from my react native application?

Comment: Check the google api, it has endpoints for writing into spreadsheets too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following node package to get this done:
[google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet)

There is also a offical package: [NodeJS Google Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs)