# Google Sheets API with React Native

Tags: react-native, google-sheets-api

I am new to React Native. I am trying to do simple [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations on a Google spreadsheet located on [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive). I've successfully implemented the packages for [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin) and [react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper) and can see my spreadsheets.

The next step is finding a React Native package that implements [Google Sheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Sheets) API v4. I've tried [Iwark's/react-native-spreadsheet](https://github.com/Iwark/react-native-spreadsheet) for *react/node.js*, but it produces errors when trying to build in a React Native  environment. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am hoping you can do this using the two libraries `googleapis and google-auth-library`.

Then initialise the APIs by doing:

```
var authClient = new googleAuth();
var auth = new authClient.OAuth2();
auth.credentials = {
  access_token: accessToken
};
this.service = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth: auth});
```

Then use the *this.service*.

If this doesn't make much sense, wait for a few hours or tomorrow. I will help you with a working copy. :)

This is what I think you should do,

1. If you have your spreadsheet public, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765542/react-native-android-application-to-fetch-and-display-data-from-google-spreadshe/42765674#42767176)
2. If your spreadsheet is private

a) You need to make the user login (use the Firebase Google login), then get the access_token and do a get with access_token in `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}` or post request, etc.

b) Make a post request in your Node.js server where you handle all of these

Note: I might help you with a working example this weekend.

Comment: one of the packages that I've tried requires google-auth-library. iirc require("google-auth-library") will not build in react-native. It produces Haste module map errors because it is a node.js package rather than react-native. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Aha, I see the issue. I am thinking for a easy solution/ workaround for now. That is have a node server, where you have all of this logic and you do get and post request based on whatever you need.
If you have time wait for a while, let me figure out if I can come up with a better solution in the app itself. :)

Comment: I see what you're saying. Yes I can wait as I don't know how to proceed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm able to make progres by running the spreadsheet package in a server environment and making requests from my rn project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
npm install tabletop
```

Import

```
import Tabletop from 'tabletop';
```

Use

```
Tabletop.init({
    key: url,
    callback: googleData => {
     console.log(googleData);
    },
    simpleSheet: true
  })
```

Publishing your Google Sheet

> url =  **File->Publish to the web**. Then click Start **publishing**